# Formidable get param not populating value passed in url

Tags: wordpress, formidable, getparameter

URL sample: http://www.samplesite.com/?companyname=abcltd

I want to grab values passed in url in a formidable hidden field. I added [get param=companyname]  in the hidden field value. Works well when i am logged in as admin.

BUt if i logout, I try to access the form from url, the value doesnt get populated in hidden field.

```
function frm_set_checked($values, $field){

if($field->id == 104){

      $values['value'] =  $_GET['companyname'] ;

   }

}

add_filter('frm_setup_new_fields_vars', 'frm_set_checked', 8, 2);
add_filter('frm_setup_edit_fields_vars', 'frm_set_checked', 8, 3);
```

also tried using hook. Same things happend. for logged in user it populates the param value in hidden field. For non-logged in user it doesn't populate param value in hidden field.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Are you sure that `$field->id == 104`? Could you print `$_GET`?

Comment: I am quiet sure about it, if I login as admin the same thing works. But not for non-logged in user

Comment: Since you are using a filter, shouldn't the $value arg be returned.

e.g.
`function frm_set_checked($values, $field){

if($field->id == 104){

      $values['value'] =  $_GET['companyname'] ;

   }
   return  $values;
}`

Answer (score 0):

The fourth parameter of an add_filter function is the number of parameters you`ll give in your function. So if your frm_set_checked has ($values, $fields) the add_filter should be add_filter('frm_setup_new_fields_vars', 'frm_set_checked', 8, 2);